# ESLint --init produces a text file with the name "=3.8.1". What is it?

Tags: eslint

When running a globally installed `eslint --init` command, a text file called `=3.8.1` is created with these contents:

```
+ eslint@4.1.1
+ eslint-config-google@0.8.0
updated 2 packages in 1.193s
```

**What is it?**

- Should I put it under version control?
- Can I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

The `eslint --init` command should create an eslint config file (`.eslintrc.*`). Your file looks more like a log file from npm or something like that. I think you are safe to delete it.